# mod_rewrite all but root

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to craft a mod_rewrite conditions and rules so that all requests to a domain other than "/" are re-mapped to a new domain as they are, while requests to "/" are mapped to a particular path on the new domain.

For instance;
siteone.domain.com/some/great/path goes to
sitetwo.domain.com/some/great/path

while;
siteone.domain.com/ goes to
sitetwo.domain.com/some/other/path

The first part is easy, and although I've read several howto's on excluding particular directories or files from a mod_rewrite rule, I cannot get the second to work. All my attempts have ended up with;
siteone.domain.com/ goes to
sitetwo.domain.com/

Following is where I am at now. I am attempting to deal with requests to root first, then everything else;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule http://sitetwo.domain.com/some/other/path [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siteone\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sitetwo.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but am going around in circles now.

The logs look as if both rules are being processed. I had assumed it would stop at the first match.

```
... (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
... (3) applying pattern 'http://sitetwo.domain.com/some/other/path' to uri '/'
... (3) applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '/'
... (2) rewrite '/' -> 'http://sitetwo.domain.com/'
... (2) explicitly forcing redirect with http://sitetwo.domain.com/
... (1) escaping http://sitetwo.domain.com/ for redirect
... (1) redirect to http://sitetwo.domain.com/ [REDIRECT/301]
```

I guess what I'm needing is some sort of if/else statement? If the first condition maths do that rewrite, else move to the second condition and rule. Is that what I'm missing?

Comment: From what I am seeing in the log, it looks like both rules are being processed. I had assumed that if the first condition and rule matched, it would perform that. The logs make it look like both patterns are being applied, which then negates the effect I am looking for...

Comment: I have tried with and without the L in the first rule.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have stumbled across the problem, and as suspected it was something silly I was missing. Adding (.*) to the first RewriteRule seems to have resolved the issue.

So, instead of

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule http://sitetwo.domain.com/some/other/path [R=301,L]
```

I needed

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://sitetwo.domain.com/some/other/path [R=301,L]
```